# extract gradient brush properties

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Where is it specified and/or is it possible to extract the gradient brush from a grid column header? I'm especially after the default gradient settings for ScrollDataGrid header in Sliverlight 4.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all your brushes will be in a file called Brushes.xaml in a Resources/Styles directory, search your solution for them. If you want to know what a specific brush being used is on a control, just open the control template for it and look for the name of the StaticResource being called for it.

Expression Blend makes this relatively simple. I think the one you're referring to is the HighLightColorBrush which then translates over to HighlightColor. Hope this helps.